# LINQ Query to match a sequence

Tags: linq, lambda, expression

I have a  result set, say clientList. And I want to make sure that **ALL** the clients in the ClientList have a Profession as "Banker". Let the result of the query be a boolean value.

How can I write the LINQ or lambda expression query to get the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if ( clientList.All(c=>c.Profession=="Banker") )
 {
  }
```

Comment: alternatively use c.Profession.Equals("Banker")... same difference though.

Answer (score 2):

```
 bool allAreBankers = ClientList.All(c=>c.Profession=="Banker");
```